# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named '_awscrt'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, amazon-transcribe

I'm working with this article [Asynchronous Amazon Transcribe Streaming SDK for Python](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/transcribe-streaming-sdk-for-python-preview/).

I'm trying to create a lambda layer for the required libraries.

I used the following command:

```
pip3 install amazon-transcribe aiofile -t .
```

But I get the following error when I use the layer in my lambda function:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named '_awscrt'
```

The same works fine with virtual environment locally. I'm not sure what's the exact issue.

I even tried installing awscrt separately but it didn't work.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built the layer on Amazon Linux and it worked fine!

The [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/mosquito/aiofile) in the repo helped:

The caio linux implementation works normal for modern linux kernel versions and file systems. So you may have problems specific for your environment. It's not a bug and might be resolved some ways:

```
1. Upgrade the kernel
2. Use compatible file system
3. Use threads based or pure python implementation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda layers .zip files need to follow a specific directory file structure. Look at this section of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) to see how it should be structured for Python. This might be your problem.

Comment: No, the directory structure is correct. Can you please try and see if it works for you? Sample code is here https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-transcribe-streaming-sdk